# Angular2: Code organisation of web service/http requests

Tags: angular

In angular 1x, I was able to separate my web service calls in a service as shown below.

```
angular.module('app.APIServices', [])

.factory('API', ['serviceBase', 'clientConfig', '$http', 'cacheService',
    function(serviceBase, clientConfig, $http, cacheService) {

        return {
            getSystemStats: function(params) {
                var params = _.merge(params, serviceBase.baseParams);
                return $http({
                    url: serviceBase.serviceBaseUri + '/GetSystemStats',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: params,
                    cache: false
                }).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                })
            }
                //  more methods in a similar way can be added.
        }
    }
);
```

and then use the above service in the controller:

```
API.getSystemStats(paramsObject).then(function(result){
    // run success logic here
},function(reason){
    // run failure
});
```

I would like to implement the same separation in **Angular2**. I would like to avoid defining the webservice urls in all the components.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the http service in your own service in Angular 2.0 as well.

Here is an example:

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http'
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class AddressBookService {

    http:Http;
    constructor(http:Http){
        this.http = http;
    }

    getEntries(){
        return this.http.get('./people.json').map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

The service defined above can then be imported into a component like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'address-book',
    templateUrl: './components/dependency-injection/address-book.html',
    providers:[AddressBookService]
})

export class AddressBook {

    result:Object;

    constructor(addressBookService:AddressBookService){
        this.result = {people:[]};
        addressBookService.getEntries().subscribe(res => this.result = res);


    }
}
```

@injectable is needed on the service in order to resolve the full DI dependency chain for both the component and the service.

In this case the service is registered as a provider at the component level. You can also register it at the application level by specifying it in the application bootstrap method.

Some more info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.0

Here is the full source for the example: https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/tree/master/components/dependency-injection

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly, And thank you for your articles at www.syntaxsuccess.com, They are indeed helpful.

Comment: How can I pass parameters to getEntries() ?