# axios giving a require not defined error in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, axios

I am trying to use axios to make Http calls in my angular 2.0 project.
The console is giving a `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error
Is this because require is a node function and not available in angular ?

I installed axios using npm install axios. 
Is this not the right way to use axios in angular ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use Angular's [Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html) class instead of axios.  Here's a [SO example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389340/angular2-code-organisation-of-web-service-http-requests).

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up doing just that.

Comment: Here's another [SO example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34450948/215945).  This one uses the async pipe in the view to implicitly subscribe on the observable object returned from Http.