# How to add a CSS class to Angular parent when using router-outlet for child

Tags: angular, dynamic

I have a structure like this

```
<!-- parent -->
<div>
  <!-- child gets injected by router -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I want to add a class to the parent div if the router produces a particular child component. I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241271/how-add-class-to-parent-in-angular-application) with presumably a correct answer but it does not use the router so it will not work for me.

Comment: There is `activate` event on `router-outlet` element. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294262/angular-2-how-to-pass-data-to-a-child-component-without-rendering-the-child-co/40298057#40298057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the `Router` into your parent component, and use `[ngClass]`.

```
constructor(public router: Router) { }
```

Then in the template:

```
<div class="container" [ngClass]="{'test' : router?.url === '/home'}">

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This will add a class called `test` if the router is set to `/home`.

You can see it in action [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-tdkjgz?file=app/app.component.ts)