# Angular - get component instance in router events

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement a title service for my angular 10 app. I need to subscribe to router events, grab the activated route's component, see if it implements `title()` getter and then use it to set the page's title. Sounds easy...

The code:

```
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.rootRoute(this.route)),
        filter((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.outlet === "primary"),
        filter(
          (route: ActivatedRoute) =>
            ComponentWithTitleBase.isPrototypeOf(route.component as any)
        ),
        map((route) => (route.component as unknown) as ComponentWithTitleBase),
        tap(console.dir)
      )
      .subscribe((comp: ComponentWithTitleBase) => {
        this.titleSvc.title = comp.title;
      });
```

But the `comp.title` is ALWAYS undefined. Even though the component does implement `get title()` getter:

```
export class AboutComponent extends ComponentWithTitleBase implements OnInit {
  get title(): string {
    return "About the demo";
  }

  ...
}
```

I see that `console.dir` outputs **AboutComponent**. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use `<router-outlet (activate)="updateTitle(componentInstance)"`event in order to get current **component instance** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294262/angular-2-how-to-pass-data-to-a-child-component-without-rendering-the-child-co/40298057#40298057

Comment: I can't because I have multiple - one inside another, etc. I don't want to go and put (activate) to all of them.

Comment: You don't need to go and put activate to all of them, you can create a directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @yurzui's idea, you can use a directive for this:

#### activated-component.directive.ts

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class ActivatedComponentsDirective {

  constructor(r: RouterOutlet, titleService: TitleService) {
    r.activateEvents.pipe(
      // takeUntil(r.destroyed),
    ).subscribe(compInstance => compInstance.title && titleService.newTitle(compInstance.title))
  }

  ngOnDestroy () {
    // destroyed.next;
    // destroyed.complete();
  }
}
```

#### title.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TitleService {

  private src = new Subject<string>();

  newTitle (t: string) {
    this.src.next(t);
  }

  constructor() { this.initConsumer() }

  private initConsumer () {
    this.src.pipe(
      /* ... */
    ).subscribe(title => {
      console.log('new title', title);
    })
  }
}
```

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/rJ4SprwVQUW4Ok8gWIZB).

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work in other module. Basically, I have AppModule/router-outlet => ChildModule/router-outlet and it works for AppModule but not for subsequent outlets... Can't figure out why. The directive is in separate module, so it's imported in both.

Comment: sorry, all good! it was because of CLI not picking up module changes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there is  a little misunderstanding. when you console.dir the `.component` you get not an **instance** of AboutComponent but a **class** of it.
thus your getter should be static if you want to access it as `component.title`

```
static get title(): string {
  return "About the demo";
}
```

Comment: not sure why, but you can't get an instance from router logic. you can also try `component.prototype.title` as your problem solution if  you like it more

Answer (score 0):

With the [@bespunky/angular-zen](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/) library you can do this:

In the template holding the router outlet:

```html
<router-outlet publishComponent></router-outlet>
```

Then, in the component that needs access to the instance:

```
import { Component     } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { RouteAware    } from '@bespunky/angular-zen/router-x';

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent extends RouteAware
{
    protected onNavigationEnd(event: NavigationEnd): void
    {
        const currentInstance = this.componentBus.instance();

        console.log(`Navigation ended. Current component instance:`, currentInstance )
    }
}
```

It is open-source and you can install the library like this:

> npm install @bespunky/angular-zen

[Here's a live example](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/RouterX%20Module/RouterOutletComponentBus) with more details.

> If your router outlet has a name, you can pass it to the `instance()` method and retrieve the corresponding outlet's component.