# HTTP PROVIDERS in @Injectable Service

Tags: javascript, http, service, angular, provider

Angular2, now in beta, my company decide to work on it a little bit.
I tried to set a request from my service. I browse all the internet, but nothing working. (Maybe posts was written before Beta release).

So, I have my boot.ts like this :

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

import {BrandsComponent} from './brands/brands.component';
import {BrandsService} from './brands/brands.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <brands></brands>
 `,
 directives: [BrandsComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
}


bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, BrandsService]);
```

My BrandsComponent inject my BrandsService.
Here my service code :

```js
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class BrandsService{
 constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Task Service created.', http);
  http.get('http://google.fr');
 }

 getBrands(){
  //return this.http.get('./brands.json');
  return [];
 }
}
```

In my console, I have the 'Task service created' log, but any ajax request is going.

I can't tell you what I've tried, cause I change my code about a billion times.

Thank for your help !

@Edit :

Here my BrandsComponent code :

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {Brand} from './brand.interface';
import {BrandsService} from './brands.service';

import {ModelsComponent} from './../models/models.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'brands',
 templateUrl: 'templates/brands/list.html',
 providers: [BrandsService],
 directives: [ModelsComponent]
})

export class BrandsComponent implements OnInit{
 public brands;
 public selectedBrand : Brand;

 constructor(private _brandsService: BrandsService) { }

 /*
 * Get all brands from brands service
 */
 getBrands(){
  this.brands = this._brandsService.getBrands();
 }

 /*
 * On component init, get all brands from service
 */
 ngOnInit(){
  this.getBrands();
 }

 /*
 * Called when li of brand list was clicked
 */
 onSelect(brand : Brand){
  this.selectedBrand = brand;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the BrandsComponent code ?

Comment: what is the error. Coz if you are getting "Task service created" log, then first you have to save the value of http.get somewhere to use if I am not wrong.

Comment: Romain : I had my BrandsComponent, thanks.
@binariedMe : Sure, but any request are visible in developer console. I assign result to var, and console log it, but I had Observer object response. I search the reason, and explication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact observables are lazy. This means that corresponding HTTP requests aren't sent before attaching some response listeners on them using the `subscribe` method.

Adding a subscribe method in the constructor of your `BrandsService` should trigger your HTTP request:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class BrandsService{
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Task Service created.', http);
    http.get('http://google.fr').subscribe();
  }
  (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank Thierry. In fact, with subscribe method, request has been correctly launched. After research of subscribe method, we can in params, set data from response like : `.subscribe(data => this.brands = data.json());`. 

If I console.log(data.json()), it's good, I had a object. But if I return this.brands, it return undefined. Maybe the return is set before the ajax response ?

Comment: Yes, in fact, you can't return `this.brands` since you're within an arrow function (i.e. a callback). You should return instead the observable: `return http.get('http://google.fr');` and call the `subscribe` method on it within the component that calls the service. This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948 ;-)

Comment: Awesome guy. Thank for your proposes ! I return from my service the http method, I in ma component where service was called, I set subscribe here and all works. I Hope this post can help many people ;)