# Calling web API from a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2.0 beta version. I need to call a web API from a service. But I didn't get any solution.

### mobileService.ts

```
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Mobile } from './datatypes/Mobile';

@Injectable()
export class MobileService {          
     constructor(public http: Http) {     
        this.http = http;
        }

getMobiles() {        
    // return an observable
    return this.http.get("api/ElectronicsAPI/Get")
        .map((responseData) => {
            return responseData.json();
        })
        .map((mobiles: Array<any>) => {
            let result: Array<Mobile> = [];
            if (mobiles) {
                mobiles.forEach((mobile) => {
                    result.push(
                        new Mobile(mobile.name,
                            mobile.price));
                });
            }
            return result;
        });
}
}
```

**Error is,**

- this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Also I haved some questions related to this topics. In that, they mention to import `map` as,

- **import 'Rxjs/add/operator/map'**

But how can I do that in TypeScript?

Is there any other way to import plugin for the map function ?

### boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following within your `mobileService.ts` file:

```
import 'Rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

This import should be done where you use the `map` method.

The following answers could help you as well:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)
- [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you for your response... But, i have some doubts in this import statement... How it will be mapped? Shall i include any script file in the index.html

Comment: In fact, you should have the `Rx.js` already included within your `index.html` file using a `script` element. The import must be done in the `mobileService.ts` file...

Comment: Now i got the solution. After doing some changes in the system.config