# Notify component when service function is complete in angular

Tags: design-patterns, angular, angular2-services

I writing a service which do a http query to the backend:

```
getPlacesForUser(){
 this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/processPlaces")
  .map(res => res.text())
  .subscribe(
    data => this.result = data,
    err => this.logError(err),
    () => console.log('Places Request completed')
  )
}
```

Now I want to update the components-side, if the request is completed:

```
processPlaces(){
 this._backendService.getPlacesForUser();
}
```

How can I communicate between the component and service?

Furthermore I searching for the best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you can return the observble directly from the `getPlacesForUser` method and attach a subscribe method on it.

- **Service**

  ```
  getPlacesForUser(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/processPlaces")
      .map(res => res.text());
  }
  ```
- **Component**

  ```
  processPlaces(){
   this._backendService.getPlacesForUser()
    .subscribe(
      data => this.result = data,
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('Places Request completed')
    );
  }
  ```

The `result` attribute corresponds to an attribute of the component you can use in the component.

You can notice that a `async` pipe is available to directly leverage observable in expressions (for example within an `ngFor` one).

I think that this answer could help you: [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to call data each and every component with Rxjs framework, Make sure services should be reusable for all component, so do much as u can do code in services and subscribe only in component :

**Services**

```
 import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';    
 import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
 import { Result} from './models/result'; // model imported
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

 @Injectable()
 export class Service {
   private _result: Result[];

   constructor(private http: Http) {
     this.result$ = new BehaviorSubject<Result[]>(this._result)
   }
   result$: BehaviorSubject<Result[]>;
   private _urlGet = '/api';

   getPlacesForUser(): void{
     this.http.get(this._urlGet)
      .map(res => JSON.parse(res.text()))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .subscribe(result => {
         this.result = result;
       })
    }
 }
```

**Component**

```
 constructor(private _service: Service)
 ngOnInit(): any {
   this._service.result$.map(result => result.filter(res => 
    res.id)).subscribe(
        result => this.result = result); // map is optional to filter json
  }
```

Comment: I had to add the following line: this.result$.next(this.result) after this.result = result in the service in order for the component to pick it up. Running Angular 8.