# Using foursquare API with Angular

Tags: angular, api, foursquare

I'm having issues figuring out how to use [Foursquare API (search capability)](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search) within my Angular application.

My project structure looks like this

```
app
  components
    app.ts
    search.ts
  services
    foursquare.ts
  typings
  boot.ts
index.html
```

**foursquare.ts** looks like this

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const CLIENT_ID = 'My client id';
const SECRET = 'My secret';
const URL : string = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+SECRET+'&v=20130815';

@Injectable()
export class FoursquareService {

 constructor(public http:Http) {
   this.http = http;
 }

 foursquareGet(data) {
   return this.http.get(URL+data).map(res => res.json());
 }
}
```

And I am trying to use it within **search.ts** in a following way

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FoursquareService} from '../../services/foursquare'

@Component({
  templateUrl : 'app/components/new-listing/new-listing.html',
  providers : [FoursquareService]
})

export class NewListingComponent {
  constructor(service : FoursquareService) {
    console.log(service.foursquareGet('&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi'));
  }
}
```

This returns an Observable inside console that I have no idea how to use, and would rather like it to return an array of JSON objects that meet the criteria. I'm trying to follow documentation on this, but have no idea what step to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `get` mezthod of the `Http` class returns an observable. You can explicitly subscribe on it and use the result within your template:

```
export class NewListingComponent {
  constructor(service : FoursquareService) {
    service.foursquareGet('&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi')
       .subscribe(data => {
         this.result = data;
       });
  }
}
```

You can also go further by leveraging the `async` pipe to let it handle the observable. In this case you can set the observable as attribute of your component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#elt of result | async">{{elt.something}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class NewListingComponent {
  constructor(service : FoursquareService) {
    this.result = service.foursquareGet('&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi');
  }
}
```

This answer could give you more hints on this: [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Where would be correct place to define result variable?

Comment: Since you want to use it in your component, it must be part of it. I mean a class attribute. It's implicit in the code I provided. But you can define it explicitly: `result: ResultClass[];` right below the line `export class NewListingComponent`.

Comment: I see, and on last question, I assume there is an import that needs to be added for RequestClass ?

Answer (score 0):

Use subscribe:

```
service.foursquareGet('&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi').subscribe(data=> this.data=data);
```

Comment: Throws an error for data (does not exist on type NewListingComponent)

Comment: define data as a member variable, or do something else with it.