# How to catch exception correctly from http.request()?

Tags: http, typescript, angular, observable

**Part of my code:**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Request, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class myClass {

  constructor(protected http: Http) {}

  public myMethod() {
    let request = new Request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://my_url"
    });

    return this.http.request(request)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError); // Trouble line. 
                                // Without this line code works perfectly.
  }

  public handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

}
```

`myMethod()` produces exception in console of browser:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.request(...).map(...).catch is not a function

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Perhaps you can try adding this in your imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

You can also  do:

```
return this.http.request(request)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('yay')
  );
```

---

Per comments:

> ## EXCEPTION: TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function

Similarly, for that, you can use:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: Thank you for help, it works. After that I has same problem with `throw()` function. I added this line `import 'rxjs/Rx';` instead. Now all operators works properly.

Comment: Did you simulate an error to see if the `.catch` really works? That `.subscribe()`  works for sure.

Comment: Yes, second problem was `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function`. It may be fixed with @MattScarpino answer or in maner from this plunker as I said above: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/server-communication/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Just import throw too: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` and don't import everything, it's too huge.

Comment: Great solution,, very helpful , I might add the (err) is of type Response

Answer (score 83):

New service updated to use the HttpClientModule and [RxJS v5.5.x](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3):

```
import { Injectable }                    from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable }                    from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, tap }               from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SomeClassOrInterface}           from './interfaces';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable() 
export class MyService {
    url = 'http://my_url';
    constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {}
    private handleError(operation: String) {
        return (err: any) => {
            let errMsg = `error in ${operation}() retrieving ${this.url}`;
            console.log(`${errMsg}:`, err)
            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                // you could extract more info about the error if you want, e.g.:
                console.log(`status: ${err.status}, ${err.statusText}`);
                // errMsg = ...
            }
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }
    }
    // public API
    public getData() : Observable<SomeClassOrInterface> {
        // HttpClient.get() returns the body of the response as an untyped JSON object.
        // We specify the type as SomeClassOrInterfaceto get a typed result.
        return this._http.get<SomeClassOrInterface>(this.url)
            .pipe(
                tap(data => console.log('server data:', data)), 
                catchError(this.handleError('getData'))
            );
    }
```

---

Old service, which uses the deprecated HttpModule:

```
import {Injectable}              from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Request} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}              from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
//import 'rxjs/Rx';  // use this line if you want to be lazy, otherwise:
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  // debug
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private _http:Http) {}
    private _serverError(err: any) {
        console.log('sever error:', err);  // debug
        if(err instanceof Response) {
          return Observable.throw(err.json().error || 'backend server error');
          // if you're using lite-server, use the following line
          // instead of the line above:
          //return Observable.throw(err.text() || 'backend server error');
        }
        return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
    }
    private _request = new Request({
        method: "GET",
        // change url to "./data/data.junk" to generate an error
        url: "./data/data.json"
    });
    // public API
    public getData() {
        return this._http.request(this._request)
          // modify file data.json to contain invalid JSON to have .json() raise an error
          .map(res => res.json())  // could raise an error if invalid JSON
          .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
          .catch(this._serverError);
    }
}
```

I use `.do()` ([now `.tap()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md)) for debugging.

When there is a server error, the `body` of the `Response` object I get from the server I'm using (lite-server) contains just text, hence the reason I use `err.text()` above rather than `err.json().error`.  You may need to adjust that line for your server.

If `res.json()` raises an error because it could not parse the JSON data, `_serverError` will not get a `Response` object, hence the reason for the `instanceof` check.

In this <kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pEKlDHlmyJ7VMeUJvnOo?p=preview)</kbd>, change `url` to `./data/data.junk` to generate an error.

---

Users of either service should have code that can handle the error:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div>{{data}}</div> 
       <div>{{errorMsg}}</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    errorMsg: string;
    constructor(private _myService: MyService ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this._myService.getData()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.data = data,
                err  => this.errorMsg = <any>err
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do this. Both are very simple. Each of the examples works great. You can copy it into your project and test it.

The first method is preferable, the second is a bit outdated, but so far it works too.

1) Solution 1

```
// File - app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { ProductModule } from './product.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService, ProductModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



// File - product.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// Importing rxjs
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; // Important! Be sure to connect operators

// There may be your any object. For example, we will have a product object
import { ProductModule } from './product.module';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
    // Initialize the properties.
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private product: ProductModule){}

    // If there are no errors, then the object will be returned with the product data.
    // And if there are errors, we will get into catchError and catch them.
    getProducts(): Observable<ProductModule[]>{
        const url = 'YOUR URL HERE';
        return this.http.get<ProductModule[]>(url).pipe(
            tap((data: any) => {
                console.log(data);
            }),
            catchError((err) => {
                throw 'Error in source. Details: ' + err; // Use console.log(err) for detail
            })
        );
    }
}
```

2) Solution 2. It is old way but still works.

```
// File - app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { ProductModule } from './product.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService, ProductModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



// File - product.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

// Importing rxjs
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
    // Initialize the properties.
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    // If there are no errors, then the object will be returned with the product data.
    // And if there are errors, we will to into catch section and catch error.
    getProducts(){
        const url = '';
        return this.http.get(url).map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        ).catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The RxJS functions need to be specifically imported. An easy way to do this is to import all of its features with `import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx"`

Then make sure to access the `Observable` class as `Rx.Observable`.

Comment: Rxjs is very big file , if u import all of it's feaures it will increse your loading time

Comment: You should not just import everything from Rxjs if you only need one or two operators.

Answer (score -4):

in the latest version of angular4 use

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

it will import all the required things.

Comment: Don't do this, it will import all of Rxjs.

Comment: And so will result in increased bundle size!