# Typescript Angular 2 How do I return JSON data from a service to a component?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm getting an error `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Image[]'` for the following code.

How do I return the json data in `image.service.ts` so that  `app.component.ts` is getting an array of Image[] types?

app.component.ts

```
  images: Image[];

  getImages() {
     this.images = this._imageService.getImageData();
   }
```

image.service.ts

```
  getImageData() {
    this._http.get('app/test.json').subscribe(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
  }
```

app/test.json

```
[{"id":"1","imageid":"1","imageurl":"http://imageur"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, we `subscribe()` to the Observable returned by `http.get()` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329086/215945).  An alternative is to return an empty array, and then push items onto that array when the data comes back from the (web) server.  Be sure to not assign `this.images` to a new array, otherwise the component will still be referencing the original empty array.

image.service.ts

```
export class ImageService {
   images = [];
   getImageData() {
       this._http.get('app/test.json').subscribe(res => {
         this.images.push(...res.json());
         // don't do this:   this.images = res.json()
       });
       return this.images;
   }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EDuR89TAZajKovpuWbUR?p=preview)</kbd>

Note that `...` is an [ES2015 feature](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread).

Comment: This worked great for my Hello Word app, is this generally considered bad practice compared to the observable option?

Comment: @ClickThisNick, well, "it depends".  With observables, it is easier to pass server errors up to the component, and handle them there. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request/35329086#35329086). But, you might have an app-wide service that handles server errors, and then maybe this approach could be considered better since you have less code to write in your component.