# Error handler in Observable is not mapped to JSON

Tags: angular, angular2-http

Error callback in subscribe is not mapped to JSON trough map function! Why?

```
this.http.get("/something")
            .map((response: any) => response.json())
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
                  // response is body of request
            }, (error: any) => {
                // error must be mapped again
                let error = JSON.parse(error._body);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the callback specified with the `map` operator isn't called in the case of errors. You need to leverage the `catch` one to do that:

```
this.http.get("/something")
        .map((response: any) => response.json())
        .catch((response: any) => Observable.throw(response.json()))
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
              // response is body of request
        }, (error: any) => {
            // error must be mapped again
            let error = JSON.parse(error._body);
        });
```

Comment: Technically, `map()` is called, but the function that it was passed as an argument does not get called because the Observable has no events, only an error.  The error propagates.

Comment: Yes, agreed with you @Mark! It's not the `map` method but the callback specified at its level. I updated my answer ;-) Thanks for pointing this out...

Answer (score 1):

Because the Observable returned from `get()` has an error, the function that `map()` was passed is not called (because no events are emitted). I.e., arrow function `(response: any) => response.json()` is not called.  Rather, the error propagates until something catches it.  If nothing catches the error, you'll see the exception in your browser console.

You can catch the error with `.catch()` and/or by supplying an error handler in `subscribe()`.

I tried to create a robust `http` error handler here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329086/215945  
It catches errors generated from `.get()` or `.json()`.