# Map http error response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to map not only the successful response but also the error?

I want to get a modified error in the subscribe function

```
request.subscribe(
    response => {
        this.user = response;
    },
    error => {
        this.error = error;
    }
);
```

I already tried this

```
let request = this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(user))
.map(
    response => response.json(),
    error => this.handleError(error) // returns a string
);
```

but `handleError` is never getting executed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what the desired behavior is?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request/35329086#35329086 to me

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you, but I'm not asking how to get `catch` to work. I needed a way to change the error object before the subscription is executed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To map the result of error response, you need to use the catch operator:

```
let request = this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(user)).map(
            response => response.json())
          .catch(
            error => this.handleError(error)
        );
```

The callback specified in the map operator is only called for successful responses.

If you want to "map" the error, you could use something like that:

```
this.http.get(...)
       .map(...)
       .catch(res => Observable.throw(res.json())
```

In this case, the mapped error will be provided to the callback defined in the second parameter of the subscribe method.

Comment: Thank you, this works. One more small question: Instead of mapping the succesful response I just want to execute a function (void) but still want `catch` to work like above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're free to do what you want in the `catch` callback: `.catch(res => { this.handleError(res); }`

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear, I want sth like a additional subscription, but only on success, that returns `Observable<any>`. If I do `.map(res => doSomething():void` it will return `Observable<void>`.

Comment: No worries! Perhaps the `do` operator to execute processing in an imperative way (not part of the data flow): `.do(res => { doSomething(res); })`

Comment: Does the generic type of error have to be the same as the one of response, or can I achieve `res: Response` and `error: any`?

Comment: In fact no. You're free to return what you want for error. It's different things...

Comment: `Observable.throw()` now returns an `ErrorObservable`. How can I get the old behaviour back?

Comment: You mean not ending the processing chain but continuing to receive events?

Comment: `Argument of type '(err: any) => ErrorObservable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, source: Observable<any>, caught: Observable<any>) => Observable<any>'. Type 'ErrorObservable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: On which line of your code do you get this error?

Comment: on `.catch(err => Observable.throw(this.handle(err)))`

Comment: With RxJS v6+ the syntax will be a bit different: `httpClient.get(...).pipe(catchError(error => throwError(error.error)))`