# How can i implement resumeOnError using observables in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am using observables and the rxJS library .

I create my observable as follows:

```
this.validate$ = new Observable(observer =>
this.validateObserver = observer).share();
```

I then push objects onto this as follows:

```
this.validateObserver.next(responseJson);
```

If there is an error in what i am fetching, i pass on the error as follows:

```
this.validateObserver.error(this.setErrorMessage(filter));
```

I subscribe to this as follows, from a different class :

```
this.uploader.validate$.subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log('result triggered');
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error triggered');
      }
```

However i want my subscriber to keep listening after it receives and error instead of terminating listening as it does currently.

Can someone help with how I would be able to resume after processing the error ?

Comment: I think the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request should help

Answer (score 0):

It's more obvious in the rxJava documentation [found here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/Observer.html) but `onError` is meant to terminate the observable. You are not supposed to call `onNext` or `onCompleted` after notifying an error.

Here is what the docs say about `onError`:

> Notifies the Observer that the Observable has experienced an error
>   condition.
>
> If the Observable calls this method, it will not thereafter
>   call onNext(T) or onCompleted().

---

One way to accomplish what you want is to create another observable for the errors and call `onNext` for that observable when you come across your error condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **doOnError**

Check here  http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/doonerror.html