# What's the observable equivalent to `Promise.reject`

Tags: http, angular, promise, observable

I had this code

```
    return this.http.get(this.pushUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as PushResult[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

I wanted to use `observable` instead of `Promise`

how can i return the error to the calling method?

What's the equivalent to  `Promise.reject` ?

```
    doSomeGet() {
        console.info("sending get request");

        this.http.get(this.pushUrl)
            .forEach(function (response) { console.info(response.json()); })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        // return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

the calling method was:

```
getHeroes() {
    this.pushService
        .doSomeGet();
        // .then(pushResult => this.pushResult = pushResult)
        // .catch(error => this.error = error);
}
```

Comment: The above code with ``Promise.reject`` uncommented works perfectly fine. I am not sure why. Do you have any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```ts
private handleError(error: any) {
    // previously 
    // return Observable.throw('Some error information');

    // now
    return throwError('Some error information');
}
```

See also [How to catch exception correctly from http.request()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request)

Comment: this method seems to be deprecated in RXJS... prefer using the throwError operator: [here the documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/throw.html)

Comment: this is deprecated.

Answer (score 25):

With RxJS 6 `Observable.throw()` has changed to `throwError()`

```
Observable.throw(new Error());

// becomes

throwError(new Error());
```

Source: [RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide - Depracations](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#user-content-howto-convert-deprecated-methods)

Answer (score 0):

With RxJS 7 `throwError(error: any)` was marked obsolete due to be removed in v8

```
throwError(new Error());

// becomes

throwError(() => new Error());
```

Source: [RxJS 6.x to 7.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.x/docs_app/content/6-to-7-change-summary.md#throwerror)