# Angular 2: http.get in Observable not handling error

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I'm using observables for Http calls, which have been working fine, but then I changed up my controllers and noticed that my code apparently isn't handling errors.

Here is a look at the code from my service (SellingMenuService):

```
public getVarieties(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.varietyListUrl).map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('error finding variety list');
        // TODO: implement error handling here.
    });
}
```

And here is the relevant code from my component:

```
constructor(public sellingMenuService: SellingMenuService) { }

getVarietyList(): void {        
    this.sellingMenuService.getVarieties().subscribe(res => {            
        console.log(res);
        this.varieties = res;
    });         
}
```

And here are some errors in my console:
[image]

If I'm getting a 500 error, shouldn't those console logs from my service above get hit? Why don't they?

Comment: [Here is the official recommended way](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) to handle exceptions on HTTP requests from _Angular.io_. There is a link to a [live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview) on Plunker at the bottom of the page (go to `/app/toh/hero.service.ts` to see the code of the HTTP client service).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have your error-handling logic inside `map()`.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

return this.http.request(request)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('yay')
  );
```

See: [How to catch exception correctly from http.request()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to catch error in the `map` method, while you should do it inside `subscribe`.

```
public getVarieties(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.varietyListUrl).map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('error finding variety list');
        // TODO: implement error handling here.
    });
}
```

You can also add third parameter to observable. It will be resolved when observable is `finalized`:

```
public getVarieties(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.varietyListUrl).map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('error finding variety list');
        // TODO: implement error handling here.
    }, () => {
        console.log("finalized")
    });
}
```

You can read more here:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: I tried your code and got the following build error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunkr?