# Return an empty Observable from an Angular2 Service

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular 2 application, which uses a service to gather data.
The service does contain the following logic:

```
/* ========== CORE COMPONENTS ========== */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

/* ========== MODELS ========== */
import { IApplicationViewModel } from './models/application.model';

/* ========== CONSTANTS ========== */
import { LogzillaServerConfiguration } from '../../app.configuration';

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    private getAllEndpoint = LogzillaServerConfiguration.host + '/api/administration/application/getAll';

    // Initializes a new instance of the 'ApplicationService'.
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    // Get all the 'logzilla' applications.
    getApplications(): Observable<IApplicationViewModel[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.getAllEndpoint)
            .map((response: Response) => <IApplicationViewModel[]>response.json().model)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    // Handle an error that occured while retrieving the data.
    // This method will throw an error to the calling code.
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        return Observable.empty();
    }
}
```

What this service does is retrieving data from an endpoint, and map it to a model, when an error does occur, I'm returning an empty `Observable`.

I also have a resolver, which is used to load the data from the service, before the active route is changed.
This resolver does contain the following logic:

```
/* ========== CORE COMPONENTS ========== */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

/* ========== APPLICATION SERVICES ========== */
import { ApplicationService } from './application.service';

/* ========== MODELS ========== */
import { IApplicationViewModel } from './models/application.model';
import { IApplicationLogLevel } from './models/applicationLevel.model';

// Defines the 'resolver' which is used to resolve the applications.
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationResolver implements Resolve<IApplicationViewModel[]> {

    // Initializes a new instance of the 'ApplicationResolver'.
constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService) { }

// Get all the registered applications.
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.applicationService.getApplications();
}
}
```

The definition of my route is:

```
{ path: 'applications', component: ApplicationComponent, pathMatch: 'full', resolve: {
            application: ApplicationResolver
        }},
```

However, when I browse to `/applications`, I'm greeted with an error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: no elements in sequence.`.

**Edit: Added component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'logzilla-applications',
    templateUrl: './src/app/pages/applications/application.template.html'
})
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {
    hasApplications: boolean;
    applications: IApplicationViewModel[];
    errorMessage: string;

    // Initializes a new instance of the 'ApplicationComponent'.
    constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
        console.log('I am here.');
    }

    // This method is executed when the component is loaded.
    ngOnInit() { 

    }
```

The constructor of my component is not event called.
How can this be resolved.

Kind regards,

Comment: Can We see `ApplicationComponent`

Comment: What happens if you replace `Observable.empty()` with `Observable.of([])`

Comment: I've added the component as an edit, but it's almost empty, so I don't see why you need it :)à

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Changing it to `Observable.of([])` does work. However, can you explain why I'm having this behavious?

Comment: @Complexity - let me add an answer with further details

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `Observable.empty()` with `Observable.of([])`. The perference of `of` over `empty` is what the official Angular [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) tutorial uses to return an empty observable, and is what I have been using in all my apps.

The difference between them seems to be whether nothing is returned, or an empty array.

From the official rxjs docs:

[`Observable.empty()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty)

> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

[`Observable.of()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of)

> Creates an Observable that emits some values you specify as arguments, immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any way how my component would now it the retrieval failed, or if no data was returned. Because I might want to show some error message when the retrieval failed.

Comment: Take a look at [`Observable.throw`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw) as well as this question [how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request)

Comment: If I implement this, again, error start popping up, indicating an exception in the resolver.

Comment: of([]).ifEmpty() returns false when subscribed to. I think you meant of(), which of().ifEmpty returns true. Oddly .from([]) is considered empty, while from() is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The resolver tries to subscribe to the given Observable and pass the first result of the Observable sequence to the component (actually the ActivatedRoute object).

But because your Observable fires the completed event before an result is emitted the resolver does not get a result. So that's where your error comes from.

You have to return either `Observable.of(null)` or `Observable.of([])` or something similar.
Then you can handle the empty input in your component.

[This](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/empty.md) page contains more information about the `Observable.empty()`function.

Comment: `Observable.of(null)` is the answer here if you have defined a type parameter of your observable (e.g. `Observable<User>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty observable by using this -

```
return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>();
```

And also you can use the type to get rid of type script error.