# Angular 2 http catch router navigation not working

Tags: angular, http, router, handleerror

I am checking the user's token logged, if the authentication fails (returns a 401 error) I want to redirect to the login. The problem I'm encountering is that when I make the error catch the router.navigate does not work.

```
constructor(private http: Http , private  router : Router )


authUser(){
        return this.http.get(this.baseEndPoint+'/auth/user',Helpers.requestAuthOptions())
            .map((response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }

 public handleError = (error) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        console.log('Hello!');//Hello appears in my console
        return Observable.throw(error);
    };
```

Comment: Try normally as `.catch(this.handleError);`

Comment: Do you get any errors here?

Answer (score 0):

Just import RxJS catch Extension.
 `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

[How to catch exception correctly from http.request()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request)