# Handling json error messages in blob http calls

Tags: angular

We have http calls like:

```
this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/api/v.1/reports/...`, 
{ responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
```

which returns blob pdfs which we further on save through FileSaver.

Problem is if server returns 4XX response with some `application/json` and message in body. In that case, we cannot find a way how to access it as `responseType` has to be set prior to request and cannot be altered later.

Is there any elegant solution for it?

Comment: Which specific code(s) are you getting? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Comment: i want the same behavior (receiving json with error message) for any 4xx response. for the sake of discussion, lets say server returns 400 with `{errorCode:1, errorMessage:"do something"}`

Comment: Authentication failures and timeouts for example would have entirely different solution.. So request is too open ended...

Comment: ok, lets stick to 400 response code.

Comment: For 400 https://angular.io/api/http/Response#statusText I'd log that and see if  the message gives you more info. Not sure if that will give you more than Bad Request. Let me know

Comment: there might be an missunderstanding. client code doesn't and cannot know what is wrong. imagine a general case where you have a form with 10 fields based on which server compiles PDF on the fly. if all goes good you get PDF (read blob(), etc...) but if server validation fails you get 400 with application/json body and error json in it which you, of course, want to show to user. but since your angular request contains definition that responseType is blob, it can't read `response.json()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150918/discussion-between-jgfmk-and-dee-zg).

Comment: I think this thread is likely to give best answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request/35329086#35329086 - subscribe/catch http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#error - retry or retrywhen was the other possibility - but catch seemed more logical

Comment: i actually came up to something. let me post as answer and please give your opinion.

Comment: Use a plunker and link it is probably best..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a few tests and this is what i did so far. It works, all as expected. But i will not accept it as answer yet but leave for some time for a community to review. If someone sees problems with this approach, please point them out in comments.

ErrorMessage is of simple format:

`{ message:string }`

Service:

```
getPDF() {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/api/v.1/reports/...`, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
      .map((res) => {
        return {
          blob: new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' }), filename: this.parseFilename(res)
        }
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        let fileAsTextObservable = new Observable<string>(observer => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (e) => {
            let responseText = (<any>e.target).result;

            observer.next(responseText);
            observer.complete();
          }
          const errMsg = reader.readAsText(res.blob(), 'utf-8');
        });

        return fileAsTextObservable
          .switchMap(errMsgJsonAsText => {
            return Observable.throw(JSON.parse(errMsgJsonAsText));
          })
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can I add an updated version of your snippet for the latest RxJs? Btw, the Angular team seems not interested in the requested feature.