# Trim text from HTTP JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, xmlhttprequest

Angular/JavaScript amateur here, working on my first project using this framework. I have a Component that uses a Service which performs a GET request to a given URL.

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jive-list',
    templateUrl: './jivelist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./jivelist.component.css']
})
export class JiveListComponent implements OnInit {
    JiveLists: String[]; //placeholder

    constructor(private JiveListService: JiveListService) { }

    getJiveList(): void {
        console.log("test");
        this.JiveListService.getData().subscribe(
            data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getJiveList();
        //console.log(this.JiveLists) //placeholder
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class JiveListService {
    API_URL = environment.JIVEAPIURL //can append endpoints where needed

    constructor (public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log("constructor runs");
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL).map((res) => res);
    }

}
```

The API URL is a local file for now, located at './assets/data/data.json'

This code essentially gets a JSON from the URL and logs it in the console. When the file is purely JSON, this works with no issues. However, the JSON that will be provided in production always starts with a string.

JSON sample:

```
throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';
{
  "id" : "123456",
  "resources" : {
   //rest of the JSON
```

I have tried the two solutions recommended [in this article](https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/developer/blog/2015/06/29/throw-allowillegalresourcecall-to-the-curb-is-true), but none of them have changed my result.

Example (attempted) solution:

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL).map((res) => res.substring(res.indexOf('{')));
    }
```

My error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 1 at Object.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43048:37) at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2513:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:75481:33) at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2512:36) at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2280:47) at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2587:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3628:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3654:17)
```

Any ideas that would help me fix this issue would be appreciated. I am using Angular 4.2.4, and using @Angular/common/HttpClientModule as my HTTP handler.

Comment: can you post your entire json sample to clarify somethings

Comment: have you try something lik this res.toString().substring... and same thing before you indexof.  I think it tried to work with a javascript object and your two function indexOf and substring not working for this reason

Comment: @qchap Same error with the toString() added

Comment: @amal It's a pretty long JSON file. The only difference between the working JSON file and the error-producing one is the string at the top.

Comment: It's maybe map that doesn't like you res. Can you try to catch correctly the exception like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326689/how-to-catch-exception-correctly-from-http-request. We can maybe have more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this instead then,

the `getData()` method in service,

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL);
}
```

the `getJiveList()` in component,

```
getJiveList(): void {
   console.log("test");
   this.JiveListService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
         data = data.toString().substring(data.toString().indexOf('{'));
         console.log(data);
      });
}
```

If this doesn't work, then may be it is likely due to way we parse the data from the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found to come from the `HttpClientModule`'s `get` method, which will automatically run `json.parse()` on the response if it is requesting a URL ending in `.json`. I was unable to find a simple fix for this on the front-end, instead I referred to a Spring API which would redirect my request and use a modified JSON-parsing method that trims the string from the file.