# Http.delete TypeError: error.json is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, http-delete

In my angular app I have a `delete button`. Upon click it shows a popup screen to ask the user if he is sure he wants to delete this. When he clicks 'yes' I send the following http.delete request to the backend.

```
  Delete(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete('apiEndpoint/' + id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => 
      Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error' )
    );
  };
```

The normal result of this call is the deleted object. However,  if my `if condition` gets triggered in the backend I return the following

```
return BadRequest(new { error = "error message" });
```

When this error gets processed it results in a `TypeError: error.json is not a function`.

This is the popup :

```
showPopup() {
this.popup.open(NguiMessagePopupComponent, {
  title: 'Delete',
  message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?',
  buttons: {
    OK: () => {
      this.service.delete(this.someId).subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['someUrl']);
      },
      error => {
        alert(error);
      });
    },
    CANCEL: () => {
      this.popup.close();
    }
  }
});
```

These are all of the imports for the service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {HttpService} from './http-service.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import { model } from 'models';
```

Comment: And `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` and `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` have been added in the service

Comment: new {error:"error message"} ":" not "=". By the way, you would use httpClient, not the "depreciated" http

Comment: This error means that your error response doesn't have json method

Comment: That's not c#, it's typescript. Please don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: @Eliseo Changed that according to one solution I found. Before it was `return BadRequest("Error message");`.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I'm aware what the error means, which is why I tried to return a BadRequest with in the format of `BadRequest( new { message = "error message"})` from a solution I found here. It didn't work however

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added the c# tag because the backend where I request the delete is in c#. If it is considered irrelevant, feel free to remove or edit the tag.

Comment: See 2nd part of that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329086/1160794

Comment: @David Tried it, when I implement the answer I get the following error again `TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function`.

Comment: It's just a matter of adding `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'`, like you already did based on your comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to call `.json()` again as you have already done it in the `.map(..)` call. Just change you catch code to reference the object returned, in your case `error.error`

```
Delete(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete('apiEndpoint/' + id)
       .map(res => res.json())
       .catch((error: any) => 
          Observable.throw(error.error || 'Server error' )
       );
};
```

In addition to this you can add

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

to your code to implement the throw function.

Comment: Tried your answer but when I try to delete the object now I get the error : `TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function`.

Comment: You can add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` to you code to implement the throw function, but if you have `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` in your code then there is something wrong elsewhere.
Can you show add all of your import statements for that file to the question please?

Comment: added the imports to the question and have just added `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` which resulted in getting a step further. Now my alert displays "Server error" from the pipe in the catch but still not displaying my custom error message

Comment: Well, that solved it ;) Could you add your comment as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great! I've edited my original answer to include my comments