# how to call http call in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

could you please tell how to call http call in angular 2 and display data using ng-repeat ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/u6LXrvGuC6f3bOT1tsaZ?p=preview

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({

    templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
})


export class AppComponent {
   toDoModel;
  constructor(private _router:Router) {
   http.get('data.json')
      .map(res => res.json())

  }

  onclck(inputValue){
    alert(inputValue)
    this._router.navigate(['Second']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to inject an `Http` instance into you component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  toDoModel;

  constructor(private _router:Router,private http:Http) {
    this.http.get('data.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

There are then two ways to display your data in an `ngFor`:

- By subscribing on the observable returned by the `get` method

  ```
  @Component({
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#elt of elements">{{elt.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    `
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    toDoModel;

    constructor(private _router:Router,private http:Http) {
      this.http.get('data.json')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.elements = data;
          });
    }
  }
  ```
- By leveraging the `async` pipe

  ```
  @Component({
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#elt of elements | async">{{elt.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    `
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    toDoModel;

    constructor(private _router:Router,private http:Http) {
      this.elements = this.http.get('data.json')
          .map(res => res.json());
    }
  }
  ```

Don't forget to specify `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bdFeiiAqrPDtFUdguw7s?p=preview.

You could also put your HTTP processing into a dedicated service as described below:

- [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-a-service-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948)

Comment: please share plunker

Comment: Regarding your plunkr, you forgot to add the `http.dev.js` file in your HTML file and add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` in your `script.js` file. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Thank you! For me, subscribe was the key.  I wasn't subscribing to the result because I didn't care about the result--I just wanted to fire and forget.  But without the subscription, it never fires!

Answer (score 0):

You need it "inject" `Http` in order to use it

```
constructor(private http: Http){
  http.get('https://...')
    .map(response  => { response.json(); })
    .subscribe(value => { this.data = value;})  
}
```

Comment: Injecting and importing are different things - you need both. See the constructor parameter.