# Angular2 @Input and http.get

Tags: input, components, angular, angular-http

I'm missing something when passing data from a component to another component. I use @Input to pass the data, that i get from an http.get request. The thing is, i get an error while trying to access an attribute from the passed input while the request hasn't been resolved.

```
//news.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Pagination} from './pagination';

@Component({
    selector: 'news',
    templateUrl: 'app/news.html',
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [Pagination]
})
export class News {

    news = [];

    pagination: Pagination;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get('http://test.com/data')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(news => this.news = news);
    }
}

//pagination.ts
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pagination',
    templateUrl: 'app/pagination.html'
})
export class Pagination {
    // page: int = 1;

    @Input() config;

    constructor() {
        // this.page = this.config.number;
    }
}

//Pagination.html
Page {{config.total}}
```

config.total generates an error on load. But doing {{config}} seems to work though.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this:

You can use Elvis operator in your pagination.html

```
Page {{config?.total}}
```

This is from Angular documentation:

*The Elvis operator (?) means that the employer field is optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be ignored.*

Second solution would be to use Async Pipe:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html

In this case you would need to rewrite your code.

Comment: Note that `async` pipe doesn't work with objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561532/215945

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first solution fits the need for now ! I couldn't find anything for this problem actuellement...

Answer (score 1):

Variable decorated with `@Input()` is not available in the constructor. You have to wait until Angular resolves the binding and access it later in [component's lifecycle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.page = this.config.number;
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP is saying that `config` comes from an HTTP request, so it might not even be available in `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As Mark Rajcok said, it comes from an HTTP request and i just tried this one and it doesn't work

Comment: @Choppy I assumed it was defined elsewhere in code. Can't give you more details how to resolve this issue without knowing how you're getting `config`. Solution Vlado suggested should work for simple use case like yours. Just keep in mind that input variables aren't available in the constructor (;

Answer (score 0):

@Vlado Tesanovic I just tried the second solution because i might need to handle the data in the constructor.
What i did :

```
//news.ts
    constructor(http: Http) {
        // http.get('http://lechiffonbleu.com:1337/news/test')
        //  .map(res => res.json())
        //  .subscribe(news => this.news = news);

        this.news = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve = http.get('http://lechiffonbleu.com:1337/news/test')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(news => this.news = news);

            console.log(this.news);
            console.log(resolve);
        });
    }
```

Well i can't figure out how to resolve the promise correctly so it doesn't throw an error in the @input in pagination.ts