# Angular2 Quickstart tutorial - replace mock data with remote http data?

Tags: angularjs, http, service, typescript, angular

**Q) Can anyone explain how to achieve this with a clear example?**

I've done the Angular2 with TypeScript tutorial here:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

I want to replace the `mock-heroes.ts` and get the `hero.service.ts` to fetch real http data.  E.g. from here:

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

But Google haven't written the next part of the tutorial.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leverage the `Http` class. After injecting it, you can use it to get data asynchronously:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#user of users | async">{{user.name}}</lu>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.users = this.http.get(
      'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

Angular2 leverages observables at this level. You can use the `async` pipe or subscribe a callback...

Don't forget to set the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstraping your application:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I use this with a "component.ts" calling a method in the "service.ts" file though? Or does it have to be done in the constructor?

Thanks.

Comment: It's related to the way you handle modules. SystemJS is responsible to load the file content on import { something } from 'module'...

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstand my question. How would I change your example so that the "getData" method is in a separate service, and it is called for example on a button click in a separate "component". Like how the tutorial I mentioned is organised already.

Comment: Oh sorry! I think that this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-a-service-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948

Answer (score 1):

Like Thierry explained, you need to bootstrap the HTTP_PROVIDERS as well as import the HTTP class on the component/service where you will do the http call.  Remember to include the http and rxjs javascripts in your index.html.

The following service replaces the mock Heroes data with your json.

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; 

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private _url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  constructor(private http: Http){}
  getHeroes() { 
    return this.http.get(this._url)
      .map(res => <any[]> res.json())
      .catch(function(err) {console.log("err")}) 
  }
}
```

To better illustrate what I mean, I made a quick [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8klON0B6XB1ieGbGfnO6?p=preview) replacing the Heroes Mock data with the http.get request using the Json you provided.  Hopefully this will be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already accepted Thierry's answer before yours appeared, but appreciate the effort and plunker example too.  Cheers.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to put an example in case others have a similar problem.  Cheers~