# Async pipe does not fill object data into template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Can anyone help me see if there is a syntax error here in my template? It does not give error, but does not fill in data into the template either:

```html
<div *ngIf="(hero | async)">
  <h2>{{hero}}</h2>
  <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div>
    <label>_id: </label>{{hero._id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

Component code

```js
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
       
    @Input() hero: Observable<Hero>;
        
    constructor(
        private _heroService: HeroService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams
    ) {}
       
    ngOnInit() {
        let _id = +this._routeParams.get('_id');
        this._heroService.loadHero(_id);
        this.hero = this._heroService.hero$;
        this.hero.subscribe(data => 
           console.log(data)
        );
    }
}
```

The `console.log(data)` prints:

> Object {_id: 11, name: "Mr. Nice"}

which means that the data is correctly retrieved.

The `<div>` block also shows up, which mean `*ngIf` sees the object as non-empty.

`<h2>{{hero}}</h2>` shows `[object Object]`.

But why the `{{hero.name}}` is not showing?

Comment: You have a few things mixed up.  `hero` is an input property, but then you assign it a value in ngOnInit() -- that's odd.  The assigned value is an Observable, which doesn't have a `name` property, which explains why `{{hero.name}}` won't work.  This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561532/215945

Comment: I updated the post and remove the @input. But still the same. The async pipe is supposed to turn the observable into hero object?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Objects are a bit tricky with the async pipe.  With an Observable that contains an array, we can use NgFor and create a local template variable (`hero` below) that gets assigned each item of the array after the async pipe extracts the array from the Observable. We can then use that variable elsewhere in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
<!-- we can't use hero here, outside the NgFor div -->
```

But with an Observable that contains a single object, I'm not aware of any way to create a local template variable that will reference that object.  Instead, we need to do something more complicated:

```
<div>{{(hero | async)?.name}}</div>
```

And we would need to repeat that for each property of the object we want to display. (The above line assumes that component property `hero` is an Observable.)

It is probably easier to assign the object (that is inside the Observable, `hero$` below) to a property of the component, using component logic:

```
this._heroService.hero$.subscribe(data => this.hero = data.json());
```

and then use NgIf or the [Elvis/safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#elvis) to display the data in the view:

```
<div *ngIf="hero">{{hero.name}}</div>
<!-- or -->
<div>{{hero?.name}}</div>
```

Comment: {{(hero | async)?.name}} won't work. I did the second way: subscribe to get data into component property and reference it in template.  Thanks for taking the time. I appreciate it.

Comment: <div>{{(hero | async)?.name}}</div>   - this is just perfect. Saved me a lot of time...

Answer (score 25):

This is now possible using the 'as' syntax, available in v4.0.0:

```
<span *ngIf="user$ | async as user; else loadingUserInfo">
 {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
</span>
<ng-template #loadingUserInfo>
  Loading user information...
</ng-template>
```

More details available in the [RFC thread on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15020).

Answer (score 22):

Another option would be to use @Input and leverage smart/dumb component approach. In your smart component you can pass the async object to the dumb component then in the dumb component you can use it like a normal object.

The idea is that your smart component deals with logic and data and the dumb component handles presentation.

Smart component:

```
<dumb-component [myHero]="hero$ | async"></dumb-component>
```

Dumb component class:

```
@Input() myHero: Hero;
```

Dumb component template:

```
<div>{{ myHero.name }}</div>
```

Comment: myHero is a string right? Shouldn't it be '<div>{{ myHero }}</div>' instead of '<div>{{ myHero.name }}</div>' ?

Comment: @guilhebl no.. myHero is of the type "Hero".

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding a precision on how to use the smart / dumb component approach in the case you need to use the async pipe and a bracket syntax.

That combine a trick found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803389/angular2-async-pipe-not-does-not-fill-object-data-into-template).

```html
< ui-gallery-image([image]="(imagesFB | async) ? (imagesFB | async)[0] : null") ></ui-gallery-image>
```

I've spend hours to find.  Hope this help.
More info on this [blog post](http://dev.sebastienlucas.com/angular-recipes/).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle a *Single Observable Object* inside an Angular 2.3.x, or Angular 4.x template is to use an async pipe with a template variable.

Here's a common goal for angular developers. Take an array of elements from redux, and pluck a single matching element from the collection. Then render that singular object in a template.

COMPONENT

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-document-view',
  templateUrl: './document-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-view.component.scss']
})
export class DocumentViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @select(['documents', 'items']) readonly documenList$: Observable<DocumentDTO[]>;
  public documentVO$: Observable<DocumentDTO>;

  constructor(private _state: NgRedux<IAppState>,
              private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _documentActions: DocumentActions) {

    _route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let modelId: number = parseInt(params['modelId']); //1          
      let documentId: number = parseInt(params['documentId']); //50
      this._documentActions.getDocument(modelId, documentId);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    //documenList holds all of the documents in our application state
    //but this view only wants a single element

    this.documentVO$ = this.documenList$.map(documents => documents.find(doc => doc.documentId === 50));
  }
}
```

VIEW

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="documentVO$ | async as dto">
    <div id="about" class="col-12">
        <div id="title" class="paper meta">
            <p>{{ dto.title }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Async pipe subscribe
2. Unsubscribe
3. Call markForCheck() for OnPush

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'product-alt',
    templateUrl: './products-alt.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ProductAltComponent implements OnDestroy {
    pageTitle: string = '';
    pageTitle$ =  (new BehaviorSubject<string>('InitialTitle'));
   
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        // Asyc pipe subscribes
        this.pageTitle$.subscribe((title: string) => {
            this.pageTitle = title;
            // call markForCheck
            this.cdr.markForCheck()
        });
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Unsubscribe
        this.pageTitle$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```