# How to consume single Observable property in view from Angular2 component using async pipe?

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, angular, observable, rxjs5

If I have a component with a property of:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { CarService } from 'someservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'car-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/cars/car.component.html'
})

export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

    model: Observable<Car>;

    constructor(
        private _carService: CarService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // begin benefit setup
        this.model = this._carService.get(5);
    }
}
```

for instance, and I want to in my view use an async pipe to subscribe to that and use the properties as text, how can you actually subscribe to it? For instance:

```
<template #mycar = "model | async" >
    <p>{{ myCar?.make }}</p> 
</template>
```

I am new to Angular2 and not sure if I am doing something wrong or not.

Comment: Looks fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, I know... but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Your question doesn't show how `model` gets a value assigned. With the code above alone it's no surprise that nothing is happening.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the post with full component.

Comment: What does `this._carService.get(5)` return?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer an Observable<Car>

Comment: I do not think you can do it this way, this person: https://github.com/escardin pointed me to the following plunker he created: http://plnkr.co/edit/YMdm2dqUvMEJgeLeftwK?p=preview.

Comment: May be this can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803389/angular2-async-pipe-not-does-not-fill-object-data-into-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you were close to a good solution.

```html
<template *ngIf = "model | async as mycar" >
    <p>{{ mycar.make }}</p> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<template #mycar = "model | async" >
    <p>{{ (myCar | async).make }}</p> 
</template>
```

Comment: wouldn't this create two subscriptions?